# JPG Welcome Image Does Not Show in Rails App

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image

I've been working on a Rails application for some time now. While developing my Rails app, I've used a temporary image that I had found online as my background image on my welcome page. However, I'm now in the final process of finishing my Rails app and I want to replace that image with a custom one. The problem is, the image does not show. Any ideas?

I have placed the image in the public/assets/images/background.jpg.

Here is the CSS:

```
.bg {
                /* The image used */
                background-image: url('/assets/background.jpg');

                /* Full height */
                height: 100%;
                max-height: 2000px;

                /* Center and scale the image nicely */
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
            }
```

Below you will find the the body html:

```
<div class="bg">
        <h2 class="w3-wide" style="font-size: 400%; text-align: center; 
        padding-top: 20%; color: white; min-padding: 30px">Fashioned For Him</h2>
    </div>
```

This results in a blank, white background. Using the exact code above, my image during the development process worked perfectly. The only difference was that I linked to the other image using the online link where it was stored.

I have tried all of the following:

- Storing the image directly in the folder with the welcome page, index.html. Then I changed the path to the image from ('/assets/background.jpg') to ('background.jpg'), yet nothing happened.
- I also placed the image directly into the public folder, and then edited the image path to match. Yet nothing happened.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is placed under public/assets and you can view the image at `http://localhost:3000/background.jpg`(assuming rails is running at port `3000`) then you should be able to link that from CSS file like
 `background-image: url('/assets/images/background.jpg');`.

Comment: When trying to link to the image like you suggested, all I get is an error. “No route matches [GET] “/background.jpg”.

Comment: I edited the image path to “/assets/images/background.jpg”. However nothing happened.

Comment: No, I was not able to view the image. It resulted in an error like I mentioned above.

Comment: What is the value of `config.public_file_server.enabled` on your production.rb under config/environments directory? If it is `false` then set it to `true`.

Comment: I’m sorry, but there is no such file, or code in my entire system. I’ve searched all my files, but nothing. I’ve even manually looked at the files in my environments directory.

Comment: So, to make sure that's not the problem, I manually inserted `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` in my production.rb under config/environments. However, nothing happend. Any more ideas?

Comment: There should be three environment specific file under config/environments directory by default. Each file represents environments specific configuration. How come you don't have these files? Which Rails version you are using and on which environment you are running the app(development/production)?
Try to run `rake assets:precompile` then try to access `http://localhost:3000/background.jpg`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant to say I don’t have that line of code anywhere in my entire system. I contain the three files: development.rb, production.rb, and test.rb. I even entered in the code `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` into my production.rb to no avail. Running `rake assets:precompile` still didn’t help. As of now, to get around this problem, I was able to store the image that I wanted online. Then I’m able to just link to it.

Comment: However it is confusing on why this is happening. I even did something as simple as placing the image in the same folder as the html file and then placing the following HTML code into my html file: `<img src=“background.jpg”>` That still didn’t work!